# Changed Comment Module and database table - how to revert changes?

Tags: 7, comments

Yesterday, I posted [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69628/page-comment-settings-and-comments-on-page-not-appearing) which was subsequently locked for being too localized. I think this is much more searchable (and I still need help!) but I'm sorry for the bad thread.

Like mentioned in that thread, I changed different files in the comments module folder and added columns to the database table. This sort of disabled comments, both the settings in page content settings and their appearance on the page normally.

I tried to fix this by: uploading a completely new 'comments' folder (I have a back up if that was a bad idea) from a new copy of the core, and deleted those table fields. Still no sign of fixing any of the problems I created.

How do I return the comments to their normal setting so I can approach the altering I was planning on doing the right way this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: **Do not hack core!**

To restore your site to a stable state, revert to the default theme, [back-up your database](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and the `sites/` sub-directory and anything below it.  Then download a fresh copy of the core and install it. Finally, restore the `sites/` sub-directory, your database, and the theme.

Having extra tables in the database that Drupal does not know about does not do any harm, but you may drop those tables that you created yourself before backing up the database.

[image: Think of the kittens]

Comment: When you say backup my database, this just means I save it (SQL file) and take it all down for the installation of the fresh core? There won't be any problems when I import that old database?

Comment: I installed new core, replaced the 'sites' folder, and replaced that new database with the old one, and I'm getting the exact same problems.

Comment: To backup the database, it is best to use the Backup and Migrate module (linked to in my answer).  It discards certain tables (such as *cache* and *sessions* you don't want to re-import to your restored site.  When you do this, you should test for potential problems after completing every step of the restoring process.  I.e. test first after installation of core, then again after restoring `sites`, and then again after importing the database.  If there still is problems, you need to describe these problems in detail in order to get help here.  You should edit your question to add such detail.

Comment: I had an earlier version of the database that I just used after reinstalling. Still copying updates everything over. I'll let you know how it goes soon.

Comment: Perfect, everything is back to normal. Can you send me in the right direction in terms of figuring out how to post/store comments with custom parameters (which can be gathered on the page) so I can display only the comments for that "page"? By this I mean I have a page that takes in parameters and I want a different set of comments for each possible parameter/id.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70195/storing-additional-parameters-for-comments if you get a chance - Thanks again!